# ssl server can not connect to https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ssh, passenger

I just configure my project with SSL server in rails using nginx and passenger.

my sever is configure successfully ,but the problem is  https connections are met with 403 forbidden whereas http connections behave normally .

Here is server configuration block.

```
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name test.example.com;
 passenger_enabled on;
 passenger_app_env development;
 root /var/www/test/public;
 return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
 #rewrite    ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

I am enable to figure out the problem. please help me.

nginx.conf

```
  user www-data;
  worker_processes auto;
  pid /run/nginx.pid;

  events {
     worker_connections 768;
     # multi_accept on;
  }

 http {

  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  # server_tokens off;

  # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  # server_name_in_redirect off;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ##
  # SSL Settings
  ##

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  # gzip_vary on;
  # gzip_proxied any;
  # gzip_comp_level 6;
  # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  # gzip_http_version 1.1;
  # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json      application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  ##
  # Phusion Passenger config
  ##
  # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
  ##

  passenger_root  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
 }


 #mail {
 #  # See sample authentication script at:
 #  # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
 # 
 #  # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
 #  # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
 #  # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
 #  server {
 #      listen     localhost:110;
 #      protocol   pop3;
 #      proxy      on;
 #  }
 # 
 #  server {
 #      listen     localhost:143;
 #      protocol   imap;
 #      proxy      on;
 #  }
 #}
```

Comment: Paste complete nginx file, I see you are redirecting http to http3 using return 301, but cant see any block with https configuration.

Comment: @MicroPyramid I edit my question

Comment: How is ssh involved here?